# Book about a boy who discovered he had superhuman abilities, and ran away from an organization that wanted to use him as a weapon

Tags: story-identification, books, powers

I’m looking for a book I think I read maybe in 2018. I don’t remember much, but I remember reading it in middle school, so I believe it would be in the more advanced part of a children's section of the library.

It goes like this: this boy ran away after discovering he had super human abilities, and was being controlled like a machine. The whole FBI/organization was after him, because he was like a weapon for the military or something. But I think he ended up being taken by said organization, and was in training by the military to be the country’s weapon.

Along the way, he finds out his parents created him for the sole purpose of experimenting on him. He’s like half-cyborg, I guess, because he had this machine inside him that controlled him. One ally he met was a tea house owner who let him stay in the upstairs of the store, it was like a old apartment.

If it helps, the cover was black, except for the outline of a door opening, which was colored in red, and the boy was running through it (the door). I think it was also part of a series of books. Anything helps, so if you know what book I’m talking about, please tell me!  Thanks so much!
Edit: I believe it was published early 2010s. The book cover was all black, there was a outline of an open door, it was colored red and the main character is running through it. This book may be hard to find, I remember searching about it when I first read it and the author wasn’t super well known. He didn’t write many books and I believe this book was one of his last. It’s surprising how much I know but just can’t remember it’s name

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this book, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, did the boy have any allies in the story, and if so, can you describe them?

Comment: I’m not sure how to reply but I hope I’m doing this right, and thank you! But well, I think I read it maybe 2018? And I remember looking it up and it was I think published around the 2010s. And I remember reading that one ally he met was a tea house owner who let him stay in the upstairs of the store, it was like a old apartment. But if it helps the cover was black except for the outline of a door opening which was colored in red, and the boy was running through it (the door).

Comment: You replied perfectly. :-) And thanks for the additional details; they could very well come in handy in identifying this book. If you remember anything else that could help, please do [edit] your question to include them.

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies the book you're looking for, please mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. Or if the only answers posted are incorrect, please indicate that with a comment so we know to keep looking. Thanks.

Comment: This is vaguely reminiscent of the movie [D.A.R.Y.L.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D.A.R.Y.L.), which also features a boy who turns out to have been created by the military with superhuman abilities as an experiment — and has to escape when the military want to terminate the experiment.  But the movie dates from 1985, and I can't find any novelisation; plus some of the details don't match, so I doubt this is the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

***[The Twelve-Fingered Boy](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15870094-the-twelve-fingered-boy)*** (2013) by John Hornor Jacobs, the first book in the *[The Twelve-Fingered Boy](https://www.goodreads.com/series/95501-the-twelve-fingered-boy-trilogy)* trilogy...?

> Fifteen-year-old fast-talking Shreve doesn’t mind juvie. He’s good at dealing contraband candy, and three meals a day is more than his drunk mother provided. In juvie, the rules never change and everyone is the same. In juvie, Shreve has life figured out.
>
> So when he’s assigned a strangely silent and vulnerable new cellmate, Jack, Shreve takes the younger boy under his wing. But all Shreve’s plans and schemes unravel when he discovers Jack is different. For one thing, Jack has six fingers per hand. For another thing, he just might have superpowers.
>
> Soon Jack has drawn the attention of the cellblock bullies as well as the mysterious and chilling Mr. Quincrux—who claims to be from the Department of Health and Human Services. But when Shreve feels Quincrux invade his mind and shuffle through his darkest memories, he knows Quincrux’s interest in Jack is far more sinister. Mr. Quincrux means to take Jack away. For what purposes, no one knows.
>
> But Shreve has another plan: escape.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Could you explain why you think this is the right book though, i.e. how it matches the one described in the question? It'd help other users to tell whether this answer is likely to be correct or not.

Comment: I read your answer and I don’t think this is the right book. The boy in the book wasn’t necessarily a bad kid. And he was mostly with himself throughout the book, getting help from from barely anyone, just the one I’ve described before. But thanks for the suggestion!